# server requirements and optimizations for my data model ( 1.5 billion relationships )

Tags: neo4j

My data model is fairly simple:

```
(n:User)-[:WANTS]->(c:Card)<-[:HAS]-(o:User)
```

Whenever a user updates a card in his `wants` list, I create `outgoing :FOLLOWS` connections to users who also have that card in their haves list. At the same time, I also create `incoming :FOLLOWS` connections from users who want cards in the user's `have` list like so:

```
// update my total wants
MATCH (u:User)-[w:WANTS]-()
WHERE u.id = 1
WITH u, SUM(w.qty) AS wqty
SET u.wqty = wqty
RETURN wqty;

// delete all my incoming and outgoing follows
MATCH (u1:User {id: 1})-[f:FOLLOWS]-() DELETE f;

// outgoing follows
MATCH (u1:User)-[w:WANTS]->(c:Card)<-[h:HAS]-(u2:User)
WHERE u1.id = 1 AND u1.id <> u2.id
WITH u1, u2, (CASE WHEN h.qty > w.qty THEN w.qty ELSE h.qty END) AS haves
WITH u1.id AS id1, u2.id AS id2, SUM(haves) as weight
MATCH (uf:User), (ut:User)
WHERE uf.id = id1 AND ut.id = id2
MERGE (uf)-[f:FOLLOWS {weight: weight}]->(ut)
ON MATCH SET f.weight = weight;

// incoming follows
MATCH (u1:User)-[h:HAS]->(c:Card)<-[w:WANTS]-(u2:User)
WHERE u1.id = 1 AND u1.id <> u2.id
WITH u1, u2, (CASE WHEN h.qty > w.qty THEN w.qty ELSE h.qty END) AS haves
WITH u1.id AS id1, u2.id AS id2, SUM(haves) as weight
MATCH (uf:User), (ut:User)
WHERE uf.id = id1 AND ut.id = id2
MERGE (uf)<-[f:FOLLOWS {weight: weight}]-(ut)
ON MATCH SET f.weight = weight;
```

I decided to include this hard-coded `:FOLLOWS` relationship every time a user updates something in his inventory because I tried querying the trade potential based on the cards they had and the query was very expensive. This way the users will be able to check trade potentials by doing the following query:

```
MATCH (u1:User {id: 1})-[f1:FOLLOWS]->(u2:User)-[f2:FOLLOWS]->u1
RETURN u2.id, f1.weight AS num_cards_i_need, f2.weight AS num_cards_they_need
```

This works very fast for my test database who only has the incoming/outgoing follow relationships calculated for 1 user.

Now on to the problem. I have a small amount of nodes: `50k users` and `14k cards`. However, each user on average follows 30k other users making roughly 1.5 billion relationships. The data store for this is expected to be around 20-30GB after I'm done loading it to neo4j.

My question is, do I need to be able to load the whole database in memory in order to achieve fast reads as well as fast and frequent write of the follows relationships? Let's say I didn't have the resources to rent some large memory instance Amazon and I'm limited to conventional server hardware, what optimizations do I need to do so that I can read and write the `:FOLLOWS` very fast?

I obviously have memory for the nodestore and I also have some memory for relationshipstores for users->cards relationship, but not for users->users relationship. Can I choose which ones get loaded to memory so in effect they are "warm"?